# Handlebars: Accessing JSON Property of Parent using child property

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this handlebars template to not use a helper.

Data:

```
{
    games:[game: {teamID:1}]
    teams:{1:{name:'Team Name'}}
}
```

Template (note that is is within a `{{#each games}}`:

```
{{#teamFetch ../this teamID 'name'}}{{/teamFetch}}
```

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('teamFetch', function(season, teamid, property){
    return season.teams[teamid][property];
});
```

I'm new to handlebars but this was the only way I could figure out how to access a specific team in the season based on the id within a game, and get a property of that team. Is there a simpler way that doesn't require a helper function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to get around not using a helper. This is because Handlebars doesn't allow you to pass a variable in their *segment-literal notation* for specifying variable paths. In the [Handlebars documentation regarding Expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html):

> To reference a property that is not a valid identifier, you can use segment-literal notation: {{#each articles.[10].comments}} {{/each}}

So...ideally, we want to be able to do something like this:

```
{{#each games}}
        {{../teams.[teamID].name}}
{{/each}}
```

But as of right now, there is no way to pass in the value of `teamID` into  `../teams.[ ].name`.

It is only capable of doing this:

```
{{#each games}}
        {{../teams.[0].name}}
{{/each}}
```

It can only interpret values, eg. `0`, and unable to resolve variables eg. `teamID`