# Dynamic each iterator in Handlebars partial?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Say I have the following JSON:

```
category: {
    a_items: [],
    b_items: []
}
```

And I have a Handlebars partial:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{stuff}}
{{/each}}
```

What I would like to do is tell the partial which array to iterate over:

```
{{> showItems items=a_items}}
```

However, the partial will try to iterate over `category.items`
which doesn't exist.

So is this possible without having to create a Helper?

p.s. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749097/handlebars-accessing-json-property-of-parent-using-child-property) would suggest not but I can't work out what my helper would do. I don't want to move the entire `{{stuff}}` section of the partial into a helper.

Comment: I think this should work just fine without any need for a helper. The only reason I can think of for you having issues is that maybe your partial call should be `{{> showItems items=category.a_items}}`? I have created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/u3ftd22k/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found. Create a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('returnKeyValue', function(obj, key, options) {
    return options.fn(obj[key]);
});
```

Pass the context to the helper:

```
{{#returnKeyValue this items}}
    {{> partialThatIteratesOverItems}}
{{/returnKeyValue}}
```

Which I call with 2 different contexts:

```
{{> partial items='a_items'}}
{{> partial items='b_items'}}
```